# window service which writer the drives info after every 5 minutes

Tags: windows, service

I want to write window service that will be executed every 5 minutes and it will write the driverinfo in database. I wrote the program. Am I logically correct? kindly anyone who can review it. Will it work or not?

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WinServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public WinServiceInstaller()
    {
        var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        //must be the same as what was set in Program’s constructor
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "service1";

        //set the privileges
        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "My Display Name";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        serviceInstaller.Description = "Description of your service";

        this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}



public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {


        GetDriveInfo();

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {


    }

    static void GetDriveInfo()
    {


         DriveInfo[]alldrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

         if (alldrives.IsReadOnly)
         {

             StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("d:\\drives.text");
             writer.WriteLine("all drives are readyonly");

         }

         else
         {

             StreamWriter writer =  new StreamWriter("d:\\driveInfo.text");

             writer.WriteLine("all drives are not ready only");
             writer.Flush();
             writer.Close();



             foreach(DriveInfo info in alldrives )
             {



                 if(info.IsReady)
                 {
                     try
                     {

                         string name = info.Name;
                         string drivetype = info.DriveType.ToString();
                         string remainingSpace = info.TotalFreeSpace.ToString();
                         string totalsize = info.TotalSize.ToString();
                         string lastaccesstime = info.RootDirectory.LastAccessTime.ToString();

                         string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

                         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

                         con.Open();

                         SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SP_INSERT_DRIVE_INFO]", con);

                         cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                         cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver_Name", name);

                         cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Driver_type", drivetype);

                         cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Remaining_Space", remainingSpace);

                         cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total_size", totalsize);

                         cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastAcess_time", lastaccesstime);

                         cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                         con.Close();
                     }

                     catch (SqlException ex)
                     { 



                     }


                 }

                 else
                 {
                        writer.WriteLine("drives are not ready");
                        writer.Close();

                 }

             }

         }



         }






       static void timer()
       {
           System.Threading.Timer timer =  new System.Threading.Timer(OnElapsedTime,null,0,18000);

           timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
       }

       private static void OnElapsedTime(object state)
       {
           GetDriveInfo();
       }





    }


}
```

Comment: I think this will be better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not asking about a problem.  You may be able to get help on Code Review.

Comment: basically i want the windows service to be executed after 5 minutes the functionm calling whether it is correct or not  private static void OnElapsedTime(object state)
       {
           GetDriveInfo();
       }